# Should a struct be typecasted before memset

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, memset

Why should I typecast a struct in memset function. I see a lot of code like the one below :

```
memset( (char*) &mFdr, 0, sizeof(FdrData) );
```

`FdrData` is a struct and memset takes a void pointer. To my understanding, I think void pointer should take any type of pointer and see every byte to whatever you want it to have. I understand 0 is converted to unsigned char. But I do not understand the significance of typecasting struct for `memset()`.

Comment: It's nonsensical, especially considering that this mostly happens directly after declaring the variable, where you could much more easily write `FdrData mFdr {0};` which achieves the same thing and has the added bonus it cannot accidentally destroy a non-POD struct (since it won't compile).

Comment: @H.Guijt It would compile if there's a one parameter constructor, with parameter convertible from `int`.

Comment: In that case it will at least still construct correctly, without blasting zeroes all over the object's memory no matter what's supposed to be there.

Comment: Since C99 there is no point to this , before that it would be undefined behaviour to omit the cast if you also did not have a prototype in scope for `memset`. So you will see it in very old code (or new code written by old timers who haven't stayed fresh)

Comment: @M.M Technically, it would still be necessary in cases where the cast resolves to a `const_cast`. Can't think of *one* such (sane) scenario, though.

Comment: Yeah most of these casts are from programmers who didn't understand the compiler's error messages. They called memset without including string.h

Comment: @M.M Thanks! Looks like that is what might be happening in my organization

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do what is in your example. Like you said, the `(char*)` has no purpose.

Many of the historical uses of `memset` (from c programmers working in c++) aren't needed (were never needed). For example you can initialize a struct with `{}`...

```
struct Thing {
    int x, y, z;
};

Thing t{}; // x = 0, y = 0, x = 0;
Thing t2; // x, y, and z could be anything
```

I can't think of the last time I used memset on a struct.

Comment: The cast was never needed in any iteration of C++